# Flutter FCM is not working when app is closed

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to make an app in Flutter that receives a push notification. When I run it on Redmi note 5 I get the notification when the app is in foreground or background but I don't get any notification when the app is terminated. On the other hand, When I run it on OnePlus 6T everything works even when the app is terminated. I think the problem here is that the app is not allowed to run in background or something but how do instagram, facebook... achieve this?

Comment: It is clear that it is working. If I am not wrong it is only not working on your redmi note 5.

Comment: Did you found any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Basically, all I had to do was go to the app settings and in there I turned on autostart in permission and it worked like magic.

Comment: It's not a good solution. Only a few apps on my phone have this permission. The rest don't, and despite that they can receive notifications event when they are off

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing a similar problem with any device, check if the device is listed here: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

The problem is, some android manufacturers customize the system with features for battery savings that just kill our app, and prevent it from working and receiving notifications in background. Some giant apps like facebook, uber, instagram work just fine because they're usually listed in a 'whitelist'.

There isn't much we as developers can do in such scenarios, but usually there is an option on the system to allow a specific app on background. The previous link clarify these use cases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the permission in manifest file then on your App startup, ask users to grant permissions.

Look at this [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

Comment: which permission to ask?

Comment: Check this Link: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-notification-fixes/

Comment: That can be a user side solution I need solution as a developer

Comment: use this permission : android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND

another Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

hope it help  you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added two app into the same Firebase project so the google-services.json get changed also for the first app, so downloading the new json file and replace it with the old one works for me.