# When receiving notifications while app is terminated nothing appear , when I open my app the terminated notification start appearing . flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, uilocalnotification, localnotification

My app notification work good in background and foreground and have this problem in terminated state

I use flutter local notification and flutter firebase messaging .

this is my firebase messaging background listing function .

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  Noti.initialize(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) ;
   Noti.showBigTextNotification(
      title: '${message.data['action']}',
      body: '${message.data['message']}',     fln: flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DioHelper.init();
  setUpServiceLocator();
  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  await CacheHelper.init();

  String? parentauthCode = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'authCode');
  String? driverAuthCode = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'driverAuthCode');
  Widget startWidget = TryingToEnter();
  if (parentauthCode != null) {
    AppConstance.parentauthCode = parentauthCode;
    startWidget = HomeScreen();
  }
  if (driverAuthCode != null) {
    AppConstance.driverauthCode = driverAuthCode;
    startWidget = DriverStartJourneyScreen();
  }

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  AppConstance.deviceToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  Noti.initialize(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);

  

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<StudentsCubit>(
            create: (context) => StudentsCubit(getIt.get<StudentRepo>())
              ..getStudentMatchList()
              ..getMyCurrentLocation()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                ProfileCubit(getIt.get<ProfileRepo>())..getUserData()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                TripsHistoryCubit(getIt.get<TripsHistoryRepo>())
                  ..getTripsHistoryList()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                MessagesCubit(getIt.get<MessageRepo>())..getMessagesList()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                NotificationsCubit(getIt.get<NotificationsRebo>())
                  ..getNotificationsList()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => DriverAuthCubit(getIt.get<DriverAuthRebo>())),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                DriverProfileCubit(getIt.get<DriverProfileRebo>())
                  ..getDriverProfileData()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => DriverHomeCubit(getIt.get<DriverHomeRebo>())
              ..getDriverStudentAssignedList()),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => DriverRoutesCubit(getIt.get<DriverRoutesRepo>())
            ..getDriverRoutesData(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => DriverMapCubit()..getMyCurrentLocation()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                DriverNotificationsCubit(getIt.get<DriverNotificationsRebo>())
                  ..getDriverNotifications())
      ],
      child: MainApp(
        startWidget: startWidget,
      )));
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget startWidget;

  MainApp({required this.startWidget, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(360, 690),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (_, context) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: startWidget,
            builder: EasyLoading.init(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

this  is my flutter local notification implementation :

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class Noti {
  
  static Future initialize(
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
     
      
    var androidInitialize =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
    var iOSInitialize = const DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
    );
    var initializationsSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize, iOS: iOSInitialize);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings);
  }

  static Future showBigTextNotification(
      {required String title,
      required String body,
      var payload,
      required FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin fln,
      }) async {
   
    var not = const  NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'SchoolGObus_horn',
    'SchoolGObus_horn',
    playSound: true,
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("bus_horn"),
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
  ) ,
        iOS:  DarwinNotificationDetails());
    await fln.show( 0 , title, body, not);
  }

  static int getRandomInteger() {
    final random = Random();
    return random.nextInt(10000);
  }
}
```

Solving terminated problem .

Comment: Your code is incomplete, share the MyApp as well

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: in which platform you're facing this issue?

Comment: thank you for trying to help I find out this question and helped me to solve the problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054706/flutter-fcm-is-not-working-when-app-is-closed